# Tosca angular table steering

Tags: java, angularjs, automated-tests, tosca

I am a tester in a Scrumteam trying to automate our test regressionset.

Our front-end is developed in Java Angular and we use Tosca testsuite to automate our testset. The problem I am encountering is as follows:

With Tosca you can scan the application and all the fields, atributes, divs, and so on are shown to the user. The moment I scan one of our datatables I see them as what they are: a table. However, every field/button/icon/etc is being scanned as a seperate object.The table has 1 body, but the individual rows are not found. Meaning that the rows within the tables are not identified.

This makes it impossible for me to perform an automated search on a table, because the rows and therefor the colums are not identified, only the header is.

Anyone ever encountered this issue with a testtool or found a sollution how to fix this in the coding of the front-end in Java Angular?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common scenario when the application under test is developed using UI Libraries, where the complex controls (e.g. Table, Combobox etc.) are rendered not as a single HTML tag (`<TABLE>` for Table or `<SELECT>` for combobox). Instead you will find bunch of other HTML tags (`<DIV>`, `<SPAN>`, `<TABLE>`, `<UL>` and what not!)

If I understood correctly, there are two ways to automate this scenario -

1. You mentioned that you are able to find a `<TABLE>` tag (The header). There good
   chances that each row in the table is itself a `<TABLE>` and that's
   why you are not able to see all the contents in a single one (you
   can cross check this in the `Content View` section of `XScan`
   window). If you just need a single row for verification (I am just
   assuming!), you can select any one of them and use `ConstraintIndex` to get to the right row data. You can also look for a parent control (basically another `<TABLE>`) which clubs all the child table. This parent table might show all the data in one place. Table Verification will work with this control. **Please remember that it is
   just a workaround and might not fit into your scenario.**
2. You can write a custom control to handle this. Custom control is a way where user can define how a control looks like. Once you implement this, Tosca will be able to recognize the table as a single control containing all the data. For more information on this, check the Tosca API reference [here](https://documentation.tricentis.com/devcorner/1010/tboxapi/topic38.html)